# How to make one display in a recursive method

Tags: java

I am building a java program that executes from console, at the code I have 2 methods. first that displays all the recursive function and the second one just displays the result.
How to display just the result or where should I add the display?

```
public static int fibonacciR(int n)  {
    if(n == 0){
        System.out.println(0);
        return 0;
    } else if(n == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return fibonacciR(n - 1) + fibonacciR(n - 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the function from your `main()` method?

Comment: @PM77-1 yeah I am doing it.

Comment: Then that is where you print the value your method returns.

Comment: @PM77-1 Can you publish the answer? It is done, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should delete the `System.out.println` statement in the recursive function. So it becomes:

```
public static int fibonacciR(int n)  {
    if(n == 0){
        //You removed the statement here!
        return 0;
    } else if(n == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return fibonacciR(n - 1) + fibonacciR(n - 2);
    }
}
```

Now in your main method:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    ...
    System.out.println(fibonacciR(someNumber)); //Here you print the result of the method
    ...
}
```

Basically what you should do is remove all the print statements in the method and put it in `main`.